# Existence and uniqueness of solution for nonlinear system

Tags: pr.probability, na.numerical-analysis, existence-theorems

Under what conditions will a solution $y \in \Re^n$ exist for this system of nonlinear equations? If it exists, will it be unique?

$$ \mu_k = \int_0^\infty g_k(x) \, f(x, y) \, dx \qquad \forall \, k = 1, \dotsm, n $$

where $\mu_k$ are constants and all functions here are continuous.

If we cannot conclude anything in general, then consider a specific case in probability theory:

$$ \begin{align}
\mu_k &= \frac{1}{Z(y)} \int_0^\infty g_k(x) \, e^{f(x, y)} \, dx \qquad \forall \, k = 1, \dotsm, n \\[1ex]
Z(y) &= \int_0^\infty e^{f(x, y)} \, dx
\end{align} $$

where $Z(y)$ is a normalizing constant while $g_k$ and $f$ are **piecewise linear** in $x$. Their exact forms depend on some data, but the following is true regardless of the data:

$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x, y) = \begin{cases}
\infty  & \text{if } \; c^T y > 0 \\
-\infty & \text{if } \; c^T y < 0 \end{cases} $$

where $c \in \Re^n$ is constant.

Comment: Do you have a model case? There could be more different approaches, according to the different situations.

Comment: For what system of nonlinear equations?

Comment: @PietroMajer I've added a model case to the question.

Comment: @AmirSagiv Why downvote? The system of nonlinear equations is already stated in the question. By the way, I'm not trying to solve a differential equation; I'm solving for $y \in \Re^n$

Comment: got it, canceled the downvote